# Introduction to Statistical Learning

Tags: machine-learning, self-study

For those that have read the book [Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://faculty.marshall.usc.edu/gareth-james/ISL/ISLR%20Seventh%20Printing.pdf), I'm having a problem understanding a certain line:

[image]

I can't seem to understand the derivation from the first equality to the second. I mean, i don't think Expectations work that way. 
I get the variance part. But, how does

$E[f(X)-\hat{f}(X)]^2$ = $[f(X)-\hat{f}(X)]^2$?

Comment: The key is that the text states $\epsilon$ is independent of $X$ and has mean zero.

Comment: Expand $\left[ f(X) - \hat f (X) + \epsilon \right]^2$ and note that $E \left[ \epsilon ^2\right] = \text{Var} (\epsilon)$

Comment: I get the variance part. But, how does $E[f(X)-\hat{f}(X)]^2$ become $[f(X)-\hat{f}(X)]^2$?

Comment: The text says that $X$, $f$ and $\hat f$ are fixed, so you can treat $f(X) - \hat f (X)$ as constant.